# Getting values from Properties in SoapUI's groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

I wrote data driver script in Groovy and it seems to be fine. Data is propertly retrieved from xls file to "Properties"

Next I am using a method to create user - I am sending simple address data do database. This is a part of it:

```
  <email>${Parametry#email}</email>
     <creationDate>${Parametry#creationDate}</creationDate>
    <customerType>${Parametry#customerType}</customerType>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <nom>${Parametry#nom}</nom>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <prenom>${Parametry#prenom}</prenom>
     <!--Optional:-->
    <customerName>${Parametry#customerName}</customerName>
     <!--Optional:-->
      <nip>${Parametry#nip}</nip>
     <addressList>
        <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
        <address>
           <type>${Property#addressListtype}</type>
           <street1>${Property#addressListstreet1}</street1>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <street2>${Property#addressListstreet2}</street2>
           <postalCode>${Property#addressListpostalCode}</postalCode>
           <city>${Property#addressListcity}</city>   
           <streetNumber>${Property#addressListstreetNumber}</streetNumber>
           <!--Optional:-->
           <apartmentNumber>${Property#addressListapartmentNumber}</apartmentNumber>
           <country>${Propert #addressListcountry}</country>
        </address>
     </addressList>
```

After sending the request I receive an error:

```
     <errCode>-20001</errCode>
     <errMessage>Nie podano kompletu danych: address.type; err=NOT_ALL_DATA(-20001)</errMessage>
```

The errMessage means that address.type data is missing. So I manually wrote "MAIN" in address.type and sent request again. The error is:

```
     <errCode>-20001</errCode>
     <errMessage>Nie podano kompletu danych: address.streetNumber; err=NOT_ALL_DATA(-20001), invalid value=</errMessage>
```

So again, is asks for another value. All the values exists in "Properties", they are no blank.

I manually put all data in  `<addressList>` and method looks fine. So it means that comunnication with "Properties" which I called "Parametry" works just fine. It just doesn't work for values in `<addressList>` and I have no idea what can cause that.

Comment: Did you try validating the request in the request editor by using `Alt+v` or `right click and validate`?

Comment: There is a problem only with postalCode. Validation
line 28: Invalid decimal value: expected at least one digit

If I put this manually Validation is Ok, by the request still returns response as above

Comment: Now I see where the problem is. In address list I call "Property" instead "Parametry"

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in code. I address list I calles "Property" instead "Parametry". After changeit works.